# Android: can not resolve com.squareup.okhttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I want to use OkhttpClient from squareup in my app, so I added the following code to build.gradle:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```

but java can't resolve it anyway:

[image]

What's the probblem here?

Comment: Please give a build.gradle file?

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync` post build.gradle

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya lol ... https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-version-300-rc1 *we're changing the project's package name from com.squareup.okhttp to okhttp3*

Comment: http://s14.postimg.org/adgu2mq8x/gradle.png here it is

Comment: @Selvin i tried that, but then it cant resolve client.open() method. is there sybstitution for it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895397/not-able-to-import-com-squareup-okhttp-okhttpclient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OkHttpClient` [has moved](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/) from package `com.squareup.okhttp` to `okhttp3`

Also URLConnection support [has moved](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to the okhttp-urlconnection module.
So you need use

```
HttpURLConnection connection = new OkUrlFactory(client).open(url);
```

Comment: OkUrlFactory also unresolved now. do i nedd to add any code to gradle?

Comment: i added compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0' to gradle but still it can't convert okhttp3.OkHttpClient to com.squareup.okhttp3.OkHttpClient did i do something wrong?

Comment: You need to change package from **com.squareup.okhttp3** to **okhttp3**